# Array index out of bounds but shouldn't be

Tags: java, arrays, exception, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm making a pretty simple java-program and I get the following error (where *n* is a random number based on previous input from console):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: n
```

the line that is supposed to cause trouble is the if-statement here:

```
for(int i = 0; 0 < x; i++){
    if(TalArray[i] < min){
         min = TalArray[i];
    }
}
```

the variable "min" is previously initzialized to TalArray[0] and is keeping track of the lowest number. All variables mentioned are int-variables

Comment: if `x` is a positive number, `0 < x` will **always** be `true`, and your loop will never terminate, unless `x` becomes negative in the loop. Don't you mean `i < x`?

Comment: the loop does terminate - by throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct code is...

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    if(TalArray[i] < min){
        min = TalArray[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: oups :S I feel embarrased ^^'

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what's the value of `x` in the code, but anyway the loop condition should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TalArray.length; i++)
```

Or like this, to avoid accessing the length at each iteration:

```
for (int i = 0, x = TalArray.length; i < x; i++)
```

The `0 < x` comparison is mistaken: you're not modifying the value of `x` inside the loop, so the loop will either enter an infinite loop or not enter the loop at all, depending on the initial value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your variable `X` is never changing so
your condition `0 < x` is always `true`.

I guess the correct condition would be

```
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```